# How to speed up the gallery section of my vue project?

Tags: javascript, image, performance, vue.js, load

i am having trouble with a section of my project. Whenever i scroll fast my project would have a black background/line appear. This would only appear to mobile devices. ***specifically*** ***phones*** I noticed the black background/line appear would appear around pages that have the most images.

Now i have tried compressing the images, disabling the animations, adding defer to load the DOM first, removed any piece of code that is background-color:black; and more. The problem still persist. And so i ask for advice. Please point me to a reference/direction to my problem.

Thank you

PS here is the link to the website to checkout ***http://silverstonergv.com/***
i am using vue.js 2.X Version-2.6.12 if you can give me critique on the code and website that would be great.
thanks!

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ImageSliderContainer',
   directives: {
    lazyload: LazyLoadDirective
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isReady: false,
      img: "",
      images: [
        {
          id: 1,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/1.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/2.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/3.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/4.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/5.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/6.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/7.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/8.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 9,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/9.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 10,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/10.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 11,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/11.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 12,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/12.webp')
        },

        {
          id: 13,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/13.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 14,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/14.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 15,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/15.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 16,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/16.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 17,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/17.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 18,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/18.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 19,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/19.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 20,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/20.webp')
        },
        {
          id: 21,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/21.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 22,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/22.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 23,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/23.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 24,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/24.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 25,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/25.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 26,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/26.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 27,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/27.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 28,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/28.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 29,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/29.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 30,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/30.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 32,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/32.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 33,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/33.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 34,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/34.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 35,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/35.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 36,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/36.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 37,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/37.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 38,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/38.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 39,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/39.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 40,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/40.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 41,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/41.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 42,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/42.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 43,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/43.webp')
        }
        ,
        {
          id: 44,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/43.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 45,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/45.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 46,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/46.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 47,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/47.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 48,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/48.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 49,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/49.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 50,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/50.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 51,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/51.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 52,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/52.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 53,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/53.webp')
        }
                ,
        {
          id: 54,
          alt: "SilverStone Project",
          src: require('../assets/img/54.webp')
        }
      ],
      currentPage: 0,
      lastElement: 0,
      curElement: 21
    }
  },
  methods: {
    btnShowMoreExplore: function() {
      if( this.currentPage <= this.NumberOfCards) {
        //document.getElementById('Gallery').scrollIntoView();
        this.currentPage++;
        this.curElement += 21;
        this.lastElement += 21;
      }
    },
    btnShowLessExplore: function() {
      if( !(this.currentPage < 0) ) {
        //document.getElementById('Gallery').scrollIntoView();
        //document.getElementById('Gallery').scrollTo();
        //Gallery.scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'});
        this.currentPage--;
        this.curElement -= 21;
        this.lastElement -= 21;
      }
    },
    showReady: function() {
      this.showReady = true;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    Show() {
      return this.images.slice(this.lastElement, this.curElement);
    },
    NumberOfCards() {
      return Math.ceil((this.images.length / 21) - 1);
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

```css
<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style defer scoped>
*, body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    color: #F9F6F6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    letter-spacing: .1vw;
    transition: 1s;
    word-spacing: .3vw;
}

body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vw;
    overflow: scroll;
}

html{ scroll-behavior: smooth; }
#ImageSliderContainer { width: 100%; }

.gallery {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color:darkorange;
    padding: 4vw 1vw;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width:20vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: rgba(161, 146, 146, 0.8);
  border: 2px solid #f39842;
  z-index:98;
  top: calc(50% - 4vw);
}

  .button-container {
    text-align: center;
     width: 100%; 
     padding: 1vw; 
  }

  .button-container-bottom {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f39842; 
    padding: 1vw;
  }
  
  .button-container-bottom .imagebutton{
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    text-align: center;
    width:12vw;
    height: 6vw;
    background-color: silver;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: white;
    z-index:98;
    margin:1vw 2vw 0 2vw;
  }

.inner-gallery {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 135vw;
  max-width: 65vw;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(20vw,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 18vw;
  grid-gap: 2vmin;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 5px solid silver;
  background-color: #f39842;
}

.translatex-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: tranform 1s ease, opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.translatex-leave-to{
  opacity: 0;
   /*transform: translateX(-100vw); */
  }

.translatex-enter-to{
  opacity: 1;
  /*transform: translateX(-250vw);*/
  }

.translatex-enter-active {
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:900px) {
  .gallery-header-container { width: 95vw; margin: 0 auto; }
  .gallery-h {
    position: relative;
    top:3vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10vw;
    margin: 6% 1% 1% 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

.inner-gallery {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(40vw,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 25vw;
  grid-gap: 2vmin;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
  .button-container-bottom .imagebutton{
    font-size: 3.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    width: 24vw;
    height: 13vw;
    background-color: silver;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: white;
    z-index:98;
    margin:1vw 2vw 0 2vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}

</style>
```

```html
<template>
  <b-container id="ImageSliderContainer" fluid>
    <!-- Filer buttons  -->
    <!--
    <b-col class="button-container">
      <button class="imagebutton">ShowLess</button>
      <button class="imagebutton">Show more</button>
      <button class="imagebutton">Show more</button>
      <button class="imagebutton">Show more</button>
    </b-col>
    -->
     <b-container id="Gallery" class="gallery" fluid>

        <transition-group class="inner-gallery"  tag="div" name="translatex" mode="out-in" :duration="300"> 
          <img id="images" v-for="Slide in Show" :key="Slide.id" :src="Slide.src" :alt="Slide.alt" rel="preload">
          <!--  <div v-for="Slide in Show" :key="Slide.id" > </div> -->
          </transition-group> 
      </b-container>
            <!-- Next/Prev Buttons -->
      <b-col class="button-container-bottom">
        <button class="imagebutton" v-on:click="btnShowLessExplore" :disabled="this.currentPage > this.NumberOfCards || this.currentPage == 0" >ShowLess</button>
        <button class="imagebutton" v-on:click="btnShowMoreExplore" :disabled="this.currentPage == this.NumberOfCards">Show more</button>
      </b-col>
      <!-- End Next/Prev Buttons -->
  </b-container>
</template>
```

Comment: Maybe you can load low-quality images before actual load (lazy-load + preload).
So when user scrolls he sees images instantly, it just will be replaced with another one, with better quality.

Comment: That is a good idea. I have decided to use Intersection Observer to find all my images, blur the images until the user scrolls to the image .Then display the high-quality images. thanks!!!